# ASP.NET MVC error 50 cannot connect to localDB

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, angular

I tried every solution I found on Stack Overflow. The code had been working previously, but when i formatted my PC for some reasons, the code stopped working and i cannot remember what I previously did to fix it.

**Connection string** to localDB:

```
    {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLOCALDB;Database=localdb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
```

This is the syntax where the **code crashes**:

```
public static void Init(OrderContext context)
        {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            if (context.Users.Any()){
                return;
                }
        }
```

**What I've tried**

I downloaded SQL server 2017 and SQL Server Managment Tools. I tried to change the connection string parameters but with no success.

My former classmates don't have this issue. I cannot find a solution for this issue, I hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: can you create the db in SQL then try to connect .if you haven't tried already

Comment: I cannot create a database file trough visual studio it gives me the same error

Comment: No, Sorry I meant in  SQL server 2017 That you downloaded

Comment: I get this error again when i try to make a sql file : https://imgur.com/a/GKKud

Comment: When you open mssql 2017 can you connect to mssql2017 and create a database in mssql2017?

Comment: i did create a localdb but i cannot find it in users/<user>/ folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In visual studio use the SQL Server Object Explorer to view the local DB server name and the DB name.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql/_static/design.png

For example in this screenshot the server name is

(localdb)\MSSqlLocalDb

The database name is

MvcMovieContext-20613

So this part of your connection string would be

```
Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLOCALDB;Database=MvcMovieContext-20613
```

So use the SQL Server Object Explorer to determine those names and adjust your connection string.

LocalDB sometimes is named ProjectV13 instead of msqsqllocaldb.  You can also have both installed.

I kind of bet your database name is not LocalDB as you have here, but you'll be able to use the above to determine the name:

```
Database=localdb
```

Comment: I dont have a localdb in visual studio anymore. so i guess that where it went wrong. How can i add a local db and attach it to the project

Comment: I don't have a local db file nor have i a sql server to connect with.

Comment: to add the local db. this link should help [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-models-and-data-access)

Comment: i fixed it by just making a new solution and copied all the files in the new solution